# How to solve a Linear Matrix Equation: AX-XA=B efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, fortran

Recently I have been working on solving some math problems using Fortran. There occurs to me that a linear matrix equation:

```
AX-XA=B
```

where A and B are known n*n matrices and X is the one need to be solved. I know this looks like a typical Lyapunov equation. However, in order to solve this equation space friendly, one can use an iterative way to get the numerical result of X when the Kronecker product:

```
A*I-I*A(T)
```

is non-singular (T means transpose).

Unfortunately, this is not my case. The Kronecker product in my problem is singular. Thus, I cannot use a space friendly iterative way to solve the problem but use a very space consuming method which generates and stores the Kronecker product explicitly!!! Then I used Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of matrix algorithm to generate the pseudoinverse of this huge matrix and used a library matrix-vector multiplication routine to solve the equation.

For small matrices, this is alright. But when the size of matrices grows (e.g. when n goes up to several hundred) my computer's memory has been completely used up. Any one can help on this so that I can use a space friendly algorithm for such a problem? Thank you very much.

S

Comment: why on earth are you using fortran77? You should be using modern fortran with allocatable arrays for this.

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the right crowd to pose this question to. I'd probably try [CompSci](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) (scientific computing).

Comment: @george I totally understand your concern. I have been checking different algorithms (including the one mentioned in the post) in both C++ and Matlab. But the program package I am dealing with is written in fortran77 and I have no intense to rewrite the entire package with modern fortran, though I plan to write something in C++ later.

Comment: no need to rewrite anything, modern fortran is completely backwards compatable with f77. I would bet you are using a modern compiler anyway so go ahead and start using modern features such as allocate. (Since you show no code im just guessing you are trying to statically allocate 100,100,100,100 arrays )

Comment: @george I have stored the inverse product explicitly because I have to use it many times. In each iteration the matrix B changes resulting to a different X to be solved. So in each iteration a matrix-vector multiplication will be carried out. If I only use the inverse once, I can certainly release the memory once I finish using it. By the way, I do use fortran90 stuff in my fortran 77 code (e.g. the dynamic memory allocation). Thus I really would like to find a way that can avoid the large memory requirement even at a cost of some more time.

Comment: Ok, I see you posted on compsci which really is a better place. http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11335/how-to-solve-a-linear-matrix-equation-ax-xa-b-efficiently You might want to change that tag to just fortran here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly an answer, but maube it will help you get some progress. If i understand your problem correctly you want to solve a sylvester equation as i.e. here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

Have you tried LAPACK, maybe: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn41/node112.html -> search for TGSY2

or maybe something like this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/stgsyl.3lapack.html

or even maybe: http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/recsy/

best of luck :)